# Newbie in Python zsh: permission denied: /Users/myName

Tags: python, macos, permission-denied

I'm trying to run Python on Terminal and typed in `~ $python` but I get this error message

```
~ $python3
zsh: permission denied: /Users/myName
```

- I dragged Python folder in the Terminal and I'm denied
- I also checked the permission of the folder, I already changed it to read & write
- I searched on some similar questions here but still no idea what to do

Comment: Thank you @lenka, I'm still trying to run but failing. Still not getting what to do

Comment: I suspect you're reading a tutorial that uses "~ $" to indicate the shell's prompt (what the shell prints to say "I'm ready for a command, enter it here:"). Your prompt probably looks quite a bit different and probably ends with a "%". That doesn't matter, what matters is that you don't enter that placeholder prompt as part of the command, *only the part after it* (in this case, "python3").

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson, yes yes. Thank you for the insight, super new in this game and I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell will expand `~` to the name of your home directory and *probably* `$python3` to an empty string (since there is probably no shell variable named `python3`), so the whole thing is equivalent to just typing the name of your home directory, which obviously cannot be executed as a command.

You probably want to type just `python3`.

Comment: Woooow, thank you so much!!! I almost given up but thank you to your answer, I already accessed it. I will study more :)